# Downgrade libreswan version inside docker alpine

Tags: docker, ipsec, alpine-linux

I configured vpn server inside docker from [this repo](https://github.com/hwdsl2/docker-ipsec-vpn-server) 10 months ago. But recently met connection errors. I found this [issue](https://github.com/libreswan/libreswan/issues/612) and want to try fix it with downgrading `libreswan` to 4.15, but don't understand how to do it correctly inside `Alpine Linux`.

What i tried:

`sudo docker exec -it ipsec-vpn-server bash`

---

`ipsec --version`

> Linux Libreswan 4.6 (XFRM) on 4.19.0-21-cloud-amd64

---

`apk list libreswan`

> libreswan-4.6-r0 x86_64 {libreswan} (GPL-2.0-or-later) [installed]

---

`apk del libreswan`

> OK: 40 MiB in 79 packages

---

`apk update`

> fetch
> https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
> fetch
> https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
> v3.15.10-29-g9ff737c7902
> [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main]
> v3.15.10-29-g9ff737c7902
> [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/community] OK: 15881
> distinct packages available

---

`ipsec restart`

> Redirecting to: rc-service ipsec restart  * Stopping ipsec ...
> [ ok ]  * Starting ipsec ... nflog ipsec capture disabled

---

`ipsec --version`

> Linux Libreswan 4.6 (XFRM) on 4.19.0-21-cloud-amd64

...Why is it still installed?

---

`apk add libreswan=4.5`

> ERROR: unable to select packages:
> libreswan-4.6-r0:
> breaks: world[libreswan=4.5]

Tell me please how to downgrade libreswan version inside docker Alpine